# Struggling with complicated INSERT

Tags: sql, excel, insert, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

I'll preface with many thanks to anyone who can help me. I am trying to get a lot of data from an old flat file DB (since shut down and not accessible) into SQL. All I have now is an excel file which links and groups the data. At least I have enough to know where to put it.

I was able to use this statement as a test and it works fine:

```
INSERT INTO Crm.Qualifier 
VALUES ('40690225-5FB3-455C-9D13-0C88C02265A2', 'OldSales', 'UNV 880 880 GRAINCART-COUNTS $22,900' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'UNV 990 990 GRAINCART-COUNTS $28,500');
```

Producing this output in the webapp to the end user using the data:

[Click here](http://screencast.com/t/hJz1G3lHla5e)

This is fine for one entry but I have over 18,000 of them and I cannot find a systematic way to use the data I have or use excel functions to write the statements for me.

The goal is to have one insert statement per GUID with all the text inserted with line breaks.

This is an example of the data, grouped by Account GUID:

[Example](http://screencast.com/t/FmBAeOhlLT)

Comment: In a previous life I used EXCEL regularly to write very complicated SQL. What is the problem preventing you from doing so here?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script which will read all of your excel data, and then insert this data into the database.

For reading excel, you can use [this](http://www.techchattr.com/how-to-read-excel-files-with-php) (if you are writing your script in PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet that should help you importing the data in the format you would like it to import.

```
Create TABLE #TMP_DATA_LOAD (ACCOUNT VARCHAR(100),DATA VARCHAR(500));
--you can generate insert statement by using text editor with your data file
--sample insert statements are as below
Insert Into #TMP_DATA_LOAD Values('40690225-5FB3-455C-9D13-0C88C02265A2','UNV 880 880 GRAINCART-COUNTS $22,900');
Insert Into #TMP_DATA_LOAD Values('40690225-5FB3-455C-9D13-0C88C02265A2','UNV 990 990 GRAINCART-COUNTS $28,500');
--umcomment below line once you are sure this is what you want in final table
--Insert into Crm.Qualifier
Select DISTINCT ACCOUNT, 'OldSales' as Comments,
REPLACE( STUFF((Select '|'+ TDL1.DATA From #TMP_DATA_LOAD TDL1
WHERE TDL1.ACCOUNT=TDL.ACCOUNT FOR Xml Path('')),1,1,''),'|',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)) DATA
FROM #TMP_DATA_LOAD TDL

Drop Table #TMP_DATA_LOAD
```

I hope this answers your question.

Note: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 database for my script. The script may change if you are using other database.